# How to see package version without install?

Tags: debian, package-management, apt

I want to see the version of a package before I install it. How can I do this?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

#### Packages known by your system / offline

You can use `apt-cache` to query the APT cache. To show the versions known by your system use `apt-cache policy`. Example:

```
apt-cache policy iceweasel  
iceweasel:                        
  Installed: 10.0.4esr-3
  Candidate: 10.0.4esr-3
  Version table:
     12.0-7 0
          1 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ experimental/main amd64 Packages
 *** 10.0.4esr-3 0
        500 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ sid/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     10.0.4esr-2 0
        500 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ testing/main amd64 Packages
```

This means iceweasel version **12.0-7** is available in experimental and has priority 1, version **10.0.4esr-3** is installed from sid and has priority 500 and **10.0.4esr-2** is in testing.

For a detailed description about the meaning of priorities have a look at [apt_preferences(5)](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=apt_preferences&sektion=5&apropos=0&manpath=Debian%20Sid&locale=en)

You can also display a brief description and some meta information about the package with

```
apt-cache show package-name
```

#### Information about all debian packages / online

If you want to get version information about all available debian packages (basically what http://packages.debian.org does) you can use [rmadison(1)](http://man.he.net/man1/rmadison) to remotely query the database. rmadison is in the devscripts package which you have to install via `apt-get install devscripts`.

```
$ rmadison iceweasel
 iceweasel | 3.0.6-3             | lenny-security    | source, alpha, amd64, arm, armel, hppa, i386, ia64, mips, mipsel, powerpc, s390, sparc
 iceweasel | 3.0.6-3             | lenny             | source, alpha, amd64, arm, armel, hppa, i386, ia64, mips, mipsel, powerpc, s390, sparc
 iceweasel | 3.5.16-11~bpo50+1   | backports/lenny   | source, alpha, amd64, armel, i386, ia64, mips, mipsel, powerpc, s390, sparc
 iceweasel | 3.5.16-14           | squeeze           | source, amd64, armel, i386, ia64, kfreebsd-amd64, kfreebsd-i386, mips, mipsel, powerpc, s390, sparc
 iceweasel | 3.5.16-15           | squeeze-p-u       | source, amd64, armel, i386, ia64, kfreebsd-amd64, kfreebsd-i386, mips, mipsel, powerpc, s390, sparc
 iceweasel | 3.5.16-15           | squeeze-security  | source, amd64, armel, i386, ia64, kfreebsd-amd64, kfreebsd-i386, mips, mipsel, powerpc, s390, sparc
 iceweasel | 10.0.4esr-2~bpo60+1 | squeeze-backports | source, amd64, i386, kfreebsd-amd64, kfreebsd-i386, s390
 iceweasel | 10.0.4esr-2         | wheezy            | source, amd64, armel, armhf, i386, ia64, kfreebsd-amd64, kfreebsd-i386, mips, mipsel, powerpc, s390, s390x, sparc
 iceweasel | 10.0.4esr-3         | sid               | source, amd64, armel, armhf, hurd-i386, i386, ia64, kfreebsd-amd64, kfreebsd-i386, mips, mipsel, powerpc, s390, s390x, sparc
 iceweasel | 11.0-4              | experimental      | source, armel
 iceweasel | 12.0-3              | experimental      | source, mips
 iceweasel | 12.0-7              | experimental      | source, amd64, armhf, hurd-i386, i386, ia64, kfreebsd-amd64, kfreebsd-i386, powerpc, s390, s390x, sparc
```

The difference between apt-cache and `rmadison` is that apt-cache shows only the information known to your system (but can be used offline) while `rmadison` shows all version of available packages

Comment: Why you choice apt-cache policy for see package information? What is the cause of you choice apt-cache instead of aptitude?

Comment: @mesuutt `aptitude show` shows only one version/the version installed. But as i have multiple repositories in my sources.list (testing, unstable, experimental) i want to know which version is available in which package. You can also have a look at `apt-cache show` which is basically like aptitude show but will show the information for multiple versions.

Comment: Thanks @UlrichDangel.I did not work with multiple package version and repository more.Now I think that apt-cache policy is more useful if you work with multiple repository :)

Comment: @UlrichDangel `aptitude` can show versions for multiple repositories since squeeze.

Comment: @mesuutt rush is right you can see multiple versions either via `aptitude show -v $PACKAGE` or the answer he posted

Answer (score 39):

In addition to other answers, in case you have a .deb package file, you can do

```
$ dpkg-deb -I package.deb
```

to see control information (name, description, version, dependencies...) and basic stats like size *or*

```
$ dpkg-deb -f package.deb Version
```

to print only version.

Examples:

- full info (note that first 4 lines are beyond typical control info)

  ```
  me@here:~$ dpkg-deb -I in/sw/minutor_2.0_amd64.deb 
   new debian package, version 2.0.
   size 131594 bytes: control archive=682 bytes.
       534 bytes,    12 lines      control              
       386 bytes,     6 lines      md5sums              
   Package: minutor
   Version: 2.0
   Architecture: amd64
   Maintainer: Sean Kasun <REDACTED>
   Installed-Size: 340
   Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14), libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1), libqt5core5
  (>= 5.0.1+dfsg), libqt5gui5 (>= 5.0.1+dfsg), libqt5network5
  (>= 5.0.1+dfsg), libqt5widgets5 (>= 5.0.1+dfsg), libstdc++6
  (>= 4.1.1), zlib1g (>= 1:1.1.4)
   Section: utils
   Priority: extra
   Homepage: http://seancode.com/minutor/
   Description: Minecraft mapping tool
    Minutor lets you view and inspect your Minecraft worlds.
    It is designed for Minecraft 1.2 and later.
  me@here:~$
  ```
- version only

  ```
  me@here:~$ dpkg-deb -f in/sw/minutor_2.0_amd64.deb Version
  2.0
  me@here:~$
  ```

Answer (score 9):

`aptitude` since squeeze has ability to show all available versions. This is very useful in case you have repositories for different releases:

```
 $ aptitude versions aptitude
i   0.6.3-3.2+squeeze1        stable               700
p   0.6.7-1                   testing,unstable     650
```

Comment: Ah this looks great. There is just some small/minor gripe  i discovered. aptitude versions seems to treat the package name as a pattern, this means something like `aptitude versions gcc` list many other packets besides the gcc package.

Comment: Hm, that's strange. At my side `aptitude versions` doesn't treat name as pattern and `aptitude versions gcc` show versions only for `gcc` package and it shows nothing about `gcc-4.1` and others. May be it is as you describe in testing or even sid, unfortunately I don't have access to such versions right now to confirm that.

Answer (score 3):

Lots of package information is found at `http://packages.debian.org/package-name`, e.g. [`http://packages.debian.org/iceweasel`](http://packages.debian.org/iceweasel).

But `aptitude` can help, too, try

```
aptitude show package-name
```

Answer (score 3):

I personnaly find `apt-cache madison` useful, as it shows in a parser-friendly form what version is available with each release :

```
apt-cache madison iceweasel | grep 'Packages$'
 iceweasel |     21.0-1 | http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian/ rc-buggy/main amd64 Packages
 iceweasel | 17.0.6esr-1 | http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian/ sid/main amd64 Packages
 iceweasel | 10.0.12esr-1+nmu1 | http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main amd64 Packages
 iceweasel | 10.0.12esr-1 | http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian/ wheezy/main amd64 Packages
```