# How to install wine-1.4 in the sid repo?

Tags: debian, package-management, wine

I want to install the latest version of Wine in my Debian box. There is `wine_1.4-0.1_i386.deb` in the `pool/w/wine/` directory in the Debian mirrors. I have added `testing`, `sid` repos in the `sources.list` file. However, the latest wine I can install is always `1.2.3-0.3`.

Run `apt-cache policy wine` shows:

```
wine:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.2.3-0.3
  Version table:
     1.2.3-0.3 0
        500 http://mirrors.xxx.com/debian/ testing/main i386 Packages
        500 http://mirrors.xxx.com/debian/ sid/main i386 Packages
     1.0.1-3.1 0
        500 http://mirrors.xxx.com/debian/ squeeze/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

The existed version `1.4-0.1` doesn't show in any sources.

I have also tried:

```
sudo apt-get install wine=1.4-0.1
```

to install the explicit version 1.4-0.1, but still no success.

How to install wine-1.4 by force? Should I download the `.deb` packages manually and run `sudo dpkg -i ...`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a small update, wine 1.4 is nowadays available in the sid repository - just run `apt-get update` and `apt-get install wine`.

Original answer:

Wine 1.4-0.1 is in the experimental repository. Just add it to your `sources.list`, run `apt-get update` and you should be able to install it.

Have a look at [How to see package version without install?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39261/how-to-see-package-version-without-install/39263#39263) which shows `rmadison` to check which suite has which version available.